# yes I tried lot but unable to find repeated value

Tags: mysql

Kindly answer if possible.
Query to select record of table repeatedly two or more times to each row.

Like:

```
ID1 Name1 Age1

ID1 Name1 Age1

ID1 Name1 Age1

ID2 Name2 Age2

ID2 Name2 Age2

ID2 Name2 Age2

.. .. An so on.
```

Comment: Why is this awful question suddenly being woken up after nearly five years?

Answer (score 1):

Combination of `UNION ALL` and `ORDER BY` will do.

```
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME)
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

The above example is for 3 repeated times. If you want more, just add more `UNION` statements.

Comment: @NizamiFirdaous But Dylan's proposal is right. The link you gave just directs us to an empty MySQL terminal window. Without the proper table definitions (_your_ table definitions) we cannot see or verify anything there.

Comment: @Mr. DylanSu! Thank you but you may check after creating any test table too it's not working.